# What is the best practice to move my dockerfile and related files to the server? (private files)

Tags: deployment, docker

I have a dockerfile, a .sh file, a nginx config file and the private keys. But on a clean server how to add those files for the first time (before making the docker image) to the server?

- Should I FTP and put those files there?
- Should I git pull my project? // but I still need the keys or I can use password
- What you do?

I'm **not** using digital ocean, and I would not like to have a private paid docker repo like https://registry.hub.docker.com/plans/

Answer (score 0):

You use a physical server or a vps ?
If you can ssh to your server, add files have so many ways.

1.The most easy way is use sftp (you can find some sftp client to do this or use ftp command line tools), only need your ssh login permission, and you can upload these file to your user home directory.
2.The other way is use scp, command like:
`scp YOUR_FILE username@ipaddressORhostname:/home/username/`
this also only need your ssh login permission

git or ftp is not a good way to push files fisrt time to server.

Comment: I already use sftp but is not automatic. I would like to have one command to retrive the docker file and it's requirements. Why do you say git is bad for first time? I have a VPS

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood  what you want to do, if it's a clean server sftp is a fastest way to put your file in the server and needn't push all files to git and then pull on the server.if you want update code in container , mount a path to container and pull code from git even though use git hooks maybe a good choice. If you have a lot of clean server want to deploy the same env there has many automatic way to do that such as salt or puppet.

Comment: Ignore my last comment , maybe you cloud use Ansible , it's based on ssh to connect server and you can write playbooks to deploy your whole docker environment in a automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

Most git remotes repos (GitHub, GitLab etc) will support a https access mechanism, the data is encrypted in transit much like sftp and ssh. you'll get a password challenge. No keys...

```
git remote add myHttpsRemote https://my/foo/bar/project.git

git pull myHttpsRemote [branch]
```

Comment: This is how I've done before. Now I'm only using sftp to send the docker folder which is 10kb. With that folder it will deploy everything by himself. Git pull...

Comment: Is there a reason you cant `docker pull` the pre built image from a registry e.g. docker hub? Then you don't build locally. If building locally is essential &  this is a repetitive task then maybe consider some config management (as suggested by @tinytub). Puppet or ainsible.